# How can i use input(int) in get and return method in Java?

Tags: java

so im just starting to study java and planning to learn it in-depth and then i wanna ask this thing because im stuck and to learn more.
im trying to use the get and return method.
i wanted to do this in an input way but i cant use the
**"int age = person1.GetAge()
System.out.println("Age:" + age)**  because it will become 2 variables (age)
i hope you understand my question and i know it sounds stupid but i wanna learn xD.

CODE:

````
//unfinished
//cant use the getAge, no idea how; the value in yrsleft is always 65 despite of the formula that i give

package practice;
import java.util.Scanner;

class person{
    String name;
    int age;
    
    void speak() {
        System.out.print("Hello my name is:" + name);
    }
    
    int retire() {
        int yrsleft = 65 - age;
        return yrsleft;
        
    }
    int GetAge() {
        return age;
    }
    
}

public class curiosity1{
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        person person1 = new person();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("What is your name:");
        String name = input.next();
        
        System.out.print("What is your age:");
        int age = input.nextInt();
        
        
        //person1.name = "John";
        //person1.age = 30;
        System.out.println("Name: " + name);
        
        int age = person1.GetAge();
        System.out.println("Age:" + age);
        

        int years = person1.retire();
        System.out.println("Years till retirement:" + years);
        

    }
}```
````

Comment: For easier to read code, you should maybe look into the [Java Naming Conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html#:~:text=Class%20names%20should%20be%20nouns,such%20as%20URL%20or%20HTML). For example, class names should begin with a capital letter.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your description is trying to tell us. But you never actually provide a `age` and `name` for your `person1`. You should maybe create a custom constructor for your `Person` class, for example `public Person(String name, int age)` and from there, save the information for your person.

Comment: @maloomeister i havent provide age and name because i want it to be inputted, and thanks for the answer, will try it xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood your question correctly, you want to do this?

```
person1.age = input.nextInt();
person1.name = input.next();
System.out.println("Age:" + person1.getAge());
```

Or you can override `toString()` method in your class (since all java classes are inherited from `Object`, which has this method) to represent your object with a string. Also, you should create a constructor for your `Person` class.

```
class Person { // always start class name with a capital letter
    int age;
    String name;

    public Person(int age, String name) {
        this.age = age; 
        this.name = name;
    }
    // Your methods and etc.
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Name:" + this.name + ". Age:" + this.age; 
    }
}
```

And then:

```
int age = input.nextInt();
String name = input.next();
Person person1 = new Person(age, name);
System.out.println(person1.toString());
```